# Was Janet Van Dyne actually visible in the first MCU Ant-Man movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015, the-wasp

When the first Ant-Man movie came out, I read that Janet was supposedly visible in the scenes when Scott transitions fully to/from the Quantum Realm.  There were screenshots shown, but I couldn't make out anything from those pictures.

Were those just rumors, or does she actually appear in some form (after the scene where she cranks up her suit the enter the missile)?

Comment: I suppose framed pictures at Pym's house don't count as "appearing in some form"? :p

Comment: I meant either of the Quantum Realm transition scenes.

Answer (score 12):

Janet van Dyne does in fact appear in the first *Ant-Man* film, albeit not in the form of Michelle Pfeiffer. Firstly, she appears in flashback, which I believe you noted in the question.

[image]

As to whether or not she appears in the Quantum Realm when Scott enters, her form is visible, just barely.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a time of when this is (like an offset from an easily findable point)?

Comment: @CTMacUser 0:42 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vC_yJE0mHQ) - it's very short indeed